# Windows 10 Build 10586 is unable to reach internet?

Tags: networking, windows-10

After updating to Windows 10 version 10586 (1511 update), I've noticed that my computer is no longer able to connect to any wired networks.

Instead, it will forever "hang" and will never receive any packets.

[image]

Upon running Windows' built-in diagnostics tool, I am noticing something even more bizarre. My Winsock system is apparently corrupt and in need of a reboot.

[image]

Running the diagnostics reports that the system can not fix the problem. Similarly, running `netsh winsock reset catalog` and `netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log` have returned no useful results.

In a fit of late-night debugging without a mind, I followed the accepted [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/windows-socket-registry-entries-missing-according/5f54e033-9d49-4de0-bf23-576653641b20) post, which only made my problems worse (breaking WiFi as well).

My system would refuse to re-install the TCP/IP protocols due to a group policy error. This computer has no group policies on it, and I am the only administrator.

I later resolved my system back to its less-crippled state by restoring the Winsock registry entries from a backup (and then a known-good computer), but that also failed to fix the issue.

My wireless internet works just fine, but I am unable to connect to Ethernet in any way, shape, or form. I'm assuming that this problem is the cause of some very deep-rooted issue with Windows that will eventually require a reinstall.

However, is there a way to fix my Ethernet capability without starting fresh?

---

**Edit:** I have updated my drivers to no avail.

> **OS:** Windows 10 Professional (build 10586)
>   **Arch:** x86_64
>   **Antivirus:** BitDefender Total Security 2016
>   **Firewall:** Provided by AV

Comment: `This computer has no group policies on it` Just to clarify this side point, but there *are* default group policies in effect. Do a Start / Run and type `gpedit.msc` to lookup or change those policies.

Comment: I had this too, and after two reboots and a complete disconnect from wifi network and disable/enable of the wifi adapter, my wifi was back (haven't tested Ethernet, don't tend to use it). What I have noticed since though is I can no longer connect to my Western Digital NAS shares (by NAS hostname or IP), not even Public ones and Windows suggests there may be errors in my winsock registry. I was due a reinstall anyway (been over a year since last clean install and that was of Win7 - Windows 10 was an upgrade to 7).  After clean install the same issues persist - something hokey with build 10586.